# Pandas: groupby and get index of first row matching condition

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` called `df`, sorted in chronological order. Each row is a visit on a website.

`df` has a column named `display` that indicates the number of times a specific page has been displayed during the visit. This column is populated by integers, 0 or greater.
`df` also has a `user` column.

I want to know how many times each user visited the site before ever seeing the business-critical page I'm interested in.

To know that, I need a user-indexed `Series` populated as follows:

- 0 if the user never displayed the page
- else, the number of rows (which is the number of visits) up to the first row where `display` is non-zero (meaning, the first visit where the user saw the page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.groupby('user').display.apply(nvisits_before_display)`

```
import numpy as np
def nvisits_before_display(x):
    try:
        return np.where(x > 0)[0].item(0) + 1
    except IndexError:
        return 0
```

What does this mean?

- `x > 0`, when applied to the column `display`, means that the page has been displayed on a given visit
- `np.where(<condition>)[0]` returns a `numpy.ndarray` containing the positions of the index (ordered integers) where the condition is met
- `item(0)` is about taking the first of these positions, meaning the first visit where the page has been displayed
- `+ 1` stands for setting value 1 to users who saw the page on their first visit
- `groupby('user')` applys the `nvisits_before_display` function to the rows belonging to each user

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier to use plain ol' argmax:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1]], columns=['user', 'display'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   user  display
0     1        0
1     1        0
2     1        1
3     2        0
4     2        1

In [13]: df.groupby('user')['display'].apply(lambda x: np.argmax(x.values))
Out[13]:
user
1       2
2       1
Name: display, dtype: int64
```

Although, for the sake of clarity (or if display wasn't boolean) I would define a new column:

```
In [21]: df['seen'] = df['display'] > 0

In [22]: df.groupby('user')['seen'].apply(lambda x: np.argmax(x.values))
Out[22]:
user
1       2
2       1
Name: seen, dtype: int64
```

*Note: my old answer said `df.groupby('user')['display'].apply(np.argmax)` which wasn't quite correct as this gave the first True **index**.*

Comment: It seems to me that this does not answer the question. The expected result should be 3 for user 1 and 2 for user 2.

Comment: It definitely feels like there should be a better way. Amusingly I'm sure this used to work (back when Series was an ndarray), I expect this means I have some broken code out there somewhere...

Comment: There still is a problem if 'display' is not only 0/1: `argmax` gives the index of the first maximum value, not the first non-zero value. We would need to convert the `display` column to Boolean first.

Comment: @ArnaudRenaud you mean there are examples where it's never seen?

Comment: No, I mean there are examples where it can be greater than 1 (the user saw the page multiples times during a single visit).

Comment: @ArnaudRenaud yup, that's what the seen column is.

Comment: As you wrote, there is another issue: if `seen` is always zero for a given user, `argmax` will return 0, just like it would for a user with a non-zero `seen` on the first row.